# android app stops working when i export it as an apk

Tags: android, google-maps, apk

I have a maps fragment in my code. When i run it using the 'Run app' in Android studio it works fine. however when i export it as a signed apk the same code does not display the map. All i get is a blank screen with the google logo on the bottom left.

this is my code:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        } else {
            fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        }
        mMap =  ((SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

And my fragment is:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context="schoolbus.tracker.datavoice.schoolbusdrawer.MapsFragment"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

i have also tried getChildFragmentManager(), getSupportFragmentManager, but nothing has worked.

once again the bug only occurs when i install it as a signed apk. otherwise the maps run fine.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you replaced the debug api key of map with release key in your application.After this only a release apk will display a google map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working, i changed

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my-key" />
```

with

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="my-key"/>
```

And added:

```
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Replace the debug api key of map with release key in your application.After this only a release apk will display a google map.

Comment: Hi i double checked the api key, but it is still not showing. i went to this link:     To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=

Comment: normally this situation happens for invalid release key was your sha fingerprint correct?please recheck it

Comment: i followed the tutorial at this page: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/displaying-sha1-certificate-fingerprint.html. and re entered my fingerprint. but the map is still not showing

Comment: did u replaced the new api key in your project. and if the new key is good again run the project and make a signed apk and run this apk the map fill definitly show(the same case happened to me if my assumption is correct u shud get the map right)

Comment: sorry, i added the release fingerprint, generated a new key and added it to my application. but my map is still blank. thank you for the trouble

Comment: the map will not work in debugmode with a release key